# How to configure TypeOrm and migrations in NestJs?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm, database-migration

I've just started a new project with NestJS.
I'm just starting to learn.

I'd like to implement a migration system.
Can you tell me the steps to follow?

I'd like to run this command :
yarn migration:create "NameOfTheMigration"

So that the migration file is created here:
`database/migrations/NameOfTheMigration`

But I can't configure all this.

Can you tell me the steps to follow?

Actually i have configure this file :

`ormconfig.ts :`

```
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

const ormconfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
  port: +process.env.POSTGRES_PORT,
  username: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
  password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
  entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity.{js,ts}'],
  synchronize: false,
  migrations: [__dirname + '/../database/migrations/*.{js,ts}'],
  migrationsRun: true,
};

export default ormconfig;
```

`ormconfig.ts :`

```
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

const ormconfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
  port: +process.env.POSTGRES_PORT,
  username: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
  password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
  entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity.{js,ts}'],
  synchronize: false,
  migrations: [__dirname + '/../database/migrations/*.{js,ts}'],
  migrationsRun: true,
};

export default ormconfig;
```

Answer (score 5):

I created a small NestJS project with typeorm and `mysql`

Store the ormconfig in separate file and create a datasource using the orm config

`src/db/ormconfig.ts`

```
import { DataSourceOptions, DataSource } from 'typeorm';

export const dataSourceOptions: DataSourceOptions = {
  type: (process.env.TYPE as any) ?? 'mysql',
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT, 10) ?? 3306,
  username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  synchronize: false,
  bigNumberStrings: true,
  multipleStatements: true,
  logging: true,
  entities: ['**/*.entity{ .ts,.js}'],
  migrations: ['dist/db/migrations/*{.ts,.js}'],
  migrationsRun: true,
};

const dataSource = new DataSource(dataSourceOptions);

export default dataSource;
```

Import the created data source in your app
`src/app.module.ts`

```
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { TypeOrmModule } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { AppController } from "./app.controller";
import { AppService } from "./app.service";
import { dataSourceOptions } from "./db/ormconfig";

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRoot(dataSourceOptions)], // data source used here
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Add scripts in package.json to generate migrations
`package.json`

```
{
  // deps and dev deps
  "scripts": {
    // other package json scripts
    "typeorm": "npm run build && npx typeorm -d dist/db/ormconfig.js",
    "migration:generate": "npm run typeorm -- migration:generate",
    "migration:run": "npm run typeorm -- migration:run",
    "migration:revert": "npm run typeorm -- migration:revert"
  }
}
```

Now, all you have to do is consume your scripts to generate migrations. Since we are creating a build to create and run the migrations, your app may not have the context of `.env` variables. I usually follow these steps for creating a migration

**Step 1:**

- Create a shell file `app-env.sh` and add all the `.env` variables with value

`app-env.sh`

```
export NODE_ENV=development
export HOST=0.0.0.0
export PORT=3000
# your other environment variables here
```

- Populate the environment variables to your shell

```
source app-env.sh
```

**Step 2:**
Generate migrations by using the following command

```
npm run migration:generate -- ./src/db/migrations/YourMigrationNameHere
```

**Step 3:**
Run the migrations with the following command

```
npm run migration:run
```

**Step 4 (Optional):**
If you wanted to revert the applied migration

```
npm run migration:revert
```

Please note that unless you close your terminal and start a new terminal, any change in `.env` will not reflect in the app (since we sourced `app-env.sh`)

Comment: What's for `dataSource` exported const?

Comment: There is another way to populate .env variables into the application using dotenv package . Install and import dotenv package 

import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()

Comment: @ShehryarTanoli that works only if you copy `.env` into `dist` folder which will not happen during build.